# How often x occurs after y happens in 3 different experimental conditions

Tags: frequency, addition

I want to find out how often x happens when y occurs between 3 different experimental conditions.

For example:
The behaviour (positive reaction, negative reaction) of 10 people was observed in 3 different places. Each person experienced each place once.

Place 1. basketball court

Place 2. tennis court

Place 3. netball court

How can I find out the proportion of people who had the same reaction in places 1 and 2, and the same reaction in places 1 and 3?

Please help if possible.

Thankyou.

Comment: You need a program? In which language?

Comment: Yes sorry. I am using R , but am very new to this program

Comment: Do you need help mathematically or programmatically?

Comment: I need some help programmatically . Specifically with writing code in R for the above problem . Thanks